# Where are some good resources for word templates for programming needs?

Tags: templates, ms-word, requirements

For example, I have a wide variety of needs for templates, like in creating project plans, project specifications, requirements etc.

But I have never created my own forms before, so it really helps to see other practical/actual examples.

Is there a good central resource for ms word templates for programmers/programming?

I have just started to read the book Code Complete by Steve McConnell, and I started seeing the need for templates to help doing better planning, specs, etc.

Even if there is no 1 site with tons of ms word templates/spreadsheets for programmers, makes me wish there was one, easy to use resource...

If you can point me to any links of template sites, that would be really helpful.

Comment: i wouldn't use word but specialized software, e.g. for planning.

Comment: Unfortunately not an option, which is why i didn't ask for any good software to use, but instead asked for templates/spreadsheets. Thank you.

Comment: Not many choices really. Take a look [here](http://www.dexform.com/download/software-architecture-document) and [here](http://robotics.ee.uwa.edu.au/courses/design/examples/example_design.pdf). But the best tip i can give is to google it properly, for example "software patterns filetype:doc"

Answer (score 1):

I have many templates available as shareware downloads at http://www.processimpact.com/goodies.shtml. A link on that page will lead to more templates for project management at my Project Initiation Resource page site.

Comment: Seriously?  I clicked in here to link to your website, and you already had!  Thanks for the books and the great resources.